# universal .htaccess to write

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting

I am using .htaccess for all my websites.

I would to make a universal `.htaccess` file to re-write to www.

for each and every domain address I have to replace on the .htaccess file

is there any tricks to get a universal which is change based on hosted server name with `HTTP_HOST` name

Comment: Why don't you start by sharing what you have already so we can work on that?

Comment: Did you actually bother to [Google it](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=htaccess+rewrite+www)?

Comment: @DaveRandom  I used to google for solutions.
Now I realize that stackoverflow is the best place to learn and to teach as well

Comment: @Shef 

that is just normal code 

`<Files ~ "^.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(digimobjobs\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.digimobjobs.com/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

**UPD**: got this rule worked locally

Comment: Should work as long as you don't use subdomains other than www.

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your `httpd.conf` or `apache.conf`, whichever you use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}       on                [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.           [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)          https://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Works for HTTPS and *default* hosts too.

Comment: Just curious what is `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$` condition for?

Comment: Sometimes there can be no `Host` request header, for example when one refers your server by an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You could stuff your rewrite rules in the httpd.conf, then it'll work for all sites.